# How to send information about mobile platform to sever

Tags: android, ios, api-design

I'm designing api for mobile clients and I have few request (about 3 from 40 endpoints) that need to be handle differently according to the client platform eg: `ios` and `android`.

At first I wanted to add extra parameter to those endpoints to show that they are platform depend. Later I've spoken with android developer and he told that he would rather send me header with those information.

Is there any preferred way of sending those informations? I don't see any pros of sending this via headers.

Comment: This is opinion based, so off topic.  But I'd agree with headers.  If you add them as parameters, then every platform has to add these parameters even if they make no sense, and you complicate your api.  Its also easy to forget.  As headers, you don't see them in the api and you can add them in your generic HTTP request class for all requests to your server, eliminating the chance of omission.  It also allows the mobile dev to post things that may not be important now but may be later (for example for now you may not care about phone model, but in the future you may need a model specific fix

Answer (score -1):

Use the [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header. It should contain enough information for you to identify the mobile operating system.

Comment: This isn't about just the OS.  Its about all the features of the device-  screen size, manufacturer, model, screen dpi, etc.  Too much for one header.

Comment: I must be missing the part where he says he cares about anything more than "the client platform", `ios` or `android`.

Comment: Because I've solved this problem a dozen times before.  The OS is the least important part of what the server needs to know.  It always starts with OS, and then becomes a good 10-20 values.